# Storing a Serialized List of Items in a Resource File

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I am creating some unit tests for our application, and I'd like to store a serialized (XML) list of classes in a resource file to be used by some of our tests, as a mock. Some of these lists could contain hundreds or thousands of items, so an individual resource entry could be quite large. Is a C# Resource file the best approach for this? Can an individual resource in a resource file contain an item this large?

I've thought about adding the serialized lists directly in my project as a file, but then I'm not sure how I would access this file in my app, without assuming a particular directory structure, which other developers may not have, because they have their source control mappings set differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to use a Resource file, do you have different versions of your list per culture you want to test?

If not, you can just as well add your XML list as an XML file straight into your Project. The maximum size of an XML file is the maximum size the OS supports; so even if you're using Windows XP, it can be up to 4 GB in length.

Comment: If I add the XML file straight into my project then how do I access it in my app? I don't want to assume any particular directory structure because other developers working on this app may not have the same TFS mapping that I do.

Comment: You mark the XML file as Content in Visual Studio; when you compile or deploy, the file will appear in the same directory as your project's DLL.

Comment: Thank you Roy. This seems to work. And it's a better approach than the resource file.